# Logic on a recursive method

Tags: scala, recursion, logic

One of my exercises requires me to write a recursive method in which a list is given, and it returns the same list with only every other element on it.

**for example : List {"a", "b", "c"} would return
              List{"a","c"}**

I am writing in scala, and I understand that it has built in library but I am not supposed to use those. I can only use if/else, helper methods,and patterns.

How could I parse thru a list using head and tail only?

so far I have this:

```
def removeLetter(list:List[String]):List[String]=list match{

 case Nil => Nil
 case n::rest=>  

  if (n == rest){  // I understand that this doesn't quite work.
     tail
   }
  else
     head::removeLetter(tail)
  }
   }
```

I am looking for the logic and not code.

Answer (score 2):

Using pattern matching, you can also deconstruct a list on it's first two elements in the same way you're doing with your `n::rest` construction. Just remember to also take lists with uneven length into account.

Comment: That is, `x :: y :: rest`. Also, in case you stoop to code, https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.0-M3/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L246 is worth pondering.

Answer (score 0):

- You correctly stated one base-case to the recursion: In case of an empty list, the result is again the empty list. `case Nil => Nil`
- There is a second base-case: A list containing a single element is again the list itself. `case x :: Nil => x :: Nil`
- You can formulate the recursive step as follows: Given a list with at least two elements, the result is a list containing the first element, followed by every other element of the list after the second element. `case x :: y :: z => x :: removeLetter(z)` (Note that here, `x` and `y` are both of type `String` while `z` is of type `List[String]`)

Remark: If you wanted to, you could also combine both base-cases, as in both cases, the input to the function is its output.