# removing alternating elements on a list in scala

Tags: scala, function, recursion

I am trying to write a recursive function in scala that takes in a list of Strings and returns a list with alternating elements from original list:

For example:

List a = {"a","b","c"}
   List b = {"a","c"}

the head should always be included.

```
def removeAlt(list:List[String], str:String):List[String]=lst match{

case Nil=> List()
case => head::tail
if(head == true)
   removeAlternating(list,head)
else
   head::removeAlternating(list,head)
```

I get a stack overflow error.

I understand that the code is incorrect but I am trying to understand the logic on how to accomplish this with only recursion and no built in classes.

Comment: Please post working code whenever you can. If you're getting a stack overflow, that means you have code that at least compiles, but what you've provided doesn't.

Comment: YOu already asked this yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35021213/logic-on-a-recursive-method

Comment: As @TravisBrown says, post code that you actually used when you got the stackoverflow. But based on the code you have posted, your error is that when recursing to handle the rest of the list, you need to pass the rest of the list, not the original list. If you pass the original, you'll only process the first element, again, and again and again => stack overflow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def remove[A](xs:List[A]):List[A] = xs match {
    case Nil => Nil
    case x::Nil => List(x)
    case x::y::t => x :: remove(t)
    }
```

if the list is empty, return a empty list.
If we're at the last element of the list, return that.
Otherwise, there must be two or more elements. Add to the first element the alternate elements of the rest of the list (and omit the second element)

Answer (score 0):

Great exercise. This is what I came up with. It is not super optimized or anything:

```
def altList[T](rest: List[T], skip: Boolean): List[T] = {

  rest match {
    case Nil => Nil
    case a :: tail if skip == false => a :: altList(tail, true)
    case a :: tail if skip == true => altList(tail, false)
  }

}
```

Comment: There's no need for the boolean. Just look ahead two elements

Comment: Yes, your example is also great, I hadn't thought of that. Although one could argue that using a boolean might have better performance and might make the code easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

A bit shorter alternative:

```
def remove[A](xs:List[A]):List[A] = xs match {
  case x::_::t => x :: remove(t)
  case _ => xs
}
```

*UPDATE*

What is not so good with the above approach is eventual stack overflow for long lists, so I would suggest tail recursion:

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

def remove[A](xs:List[A]):List[A] = {
  @tailrec
  def remove_r(xs:List[A], ys:List[A]):List[A] = xs match {
    case x::_::t => remove_r(t, x::ys)
    case _ => xs ++ ys
  }
  remove_r(xs, Nil).reverse
}
```